# Developing android apps in visual studio

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio

I am familiar with visual studio web developer and know how to create web applications using asp.net , c#.

I also have some knowledge of java but I am more familiar with c#.

Can I develop android apps in visual studio using c# ?

What can be the best tool which will help an android begginer like me with the above skillset. Kindly point out helpful tutorials supporting your suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just search google before asking questions...have you heard about xamrin ? it is used to make mobile apps using c#..you can integrate with visual studio also..
http://xamarin.com/

Comment: Thanks shreyansh. Yes I found monodroid and xamarin , but want to have expert advices like which one is best for a begginer and good articles for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since there are little people using C# to develop Android application, once you got a problem in programming, there may be no solution because no one have ever encounter this problem.
2. The bug of Android platform will be extended by C# because both Java and C# invoke the native API of Android. What's more, using C# will lead to more bugs due to the language itself.
3. Java is very similar to C#, it won't cost more than one month for a C# programmer to learn Java and become a skillful Java programmer, and using java to develop Android application is more convince than C#.So, Why not try Java?

Comment: I have once developed basic j2ee web app which does CRUD operations. How similar is android development in java to a basic j2ee web app in which servlet is used?

Comment: You know, Android programming is based on Java. If you have some knowledge about Java SE, Which is necessary for J2EE, you can goto the Android develop official site: http://developer.android.com/index.html and download some of the samples, you will see how the Android Codes looks like. Android develop is not difficult to learn for a Java programmer~

Answer (score 0):

**YES YOU CAN!**

There is a cross platform tool called Xamarin that lets you to build mobile apps with C# and you can deploy at both platforms just by writing one program although these are a few reasons native is better:

1. The community is much bigger.
2. Apps that are made with Cross Platform tools don't look that great and it works slower.
3. The experience is not that pleasant.

Although if you are fine with those reasons go for it!!!